# RelativeLayout background drawable overlap content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-background

I have a 9-patch drawable(date_time). And i want to place this drawable behind Relative Layout content, so all child views should be drawn on top of this image.
Here is xml Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_map_address"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/date_time">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_map_distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_map_distance"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_map_distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_map_distance"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:text="2,7 км"
                fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_map_path"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_map_distance"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_map_path"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_map_path"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_map_path"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:text="3,2 км"
                fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

But somehow this background overlaps all child content.
Here is shown what is happening.

[image: Overlapping content]

But if i replace

```
android:background="@drawable/date_time"
```

to

```
android:background="#0000FF"
```

Everything is fine and the output is next:

[image]

Can you explain me what i am doing wrong?

Update:
Here is my 9-patch drawable.

[image]

Comment: Post your 9-patch drawable, content indicators are probably incorrect.

Comment: @blipinsk i have added drawable. 
Also i can upload it to some imagehost if you need it for tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as I thought your content indicators are incorrect (unless you wanna introduce such a content padding with your 9-patch). Try this instead:

[image: 9-patch]

Right and bottom guides, determine which part (or how much) of your `drawable` should be occupied by your content. You've set this region to really small space, and set a fixed height of your `Layout`. In other words: 9-patch forced your `Layout` to let its children occupy only a small, region of your view (which was limited by you not letting your `Layout` stretch).

Comment: Yes. You was totally right. Finally i understand how this 9-patch magic is actually working. Thanks.